# Fragment id linking in wagtail's rich text content

Tags: wagtail

I have a bunch of content in a Wagtail 2.0 rich text field that looks like

```
Page heading
(intro blurb)

heading 1
(heading-1-relevant text)

heading 2
(heading-2-relevant text)

...
```

and I would like to give each heading an `id` so that any text can be made a link to jump to the relevant content. I can't seem to find an option to give headings an explicit `id`, and the "link" button in the rich text editor does not seem to let me pick active fragment identifiers in the content.

Is there a way to add fragment identifier based navigation on the same page work with Wagtail's rich text editor?

Comment: There are two separate questions here: how to add ids on headings in rich text, and how to add links with fragment identifiers. Neither of these have simple answers in Wagtail right now (sob), so they probably warrant separate questions.

For the links with fragment identifiers, see https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/1049. I'll drop a comment there to explain how this could work

Comment: For `id` on the headings, Wagtail doesn't provide this level of customisation for rich text content at the moment. Your best bet "right now" is StreamField, as @nimasmi described, with the limitations you described for content creators. A way forward would be https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/4223 _if_ what you want is auto-generated ids based on context, ref counting, or block text.

Comment: If what you want is user-controlled ids, then there is no way to customise the rich text editor heading blocks rendering to add a field there. Your best bet would be to create a custom entity (like in https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/1049#issuecomment-375815036, and the official docs "Stock") that would allow authors to place a tag with an id on arbitrary text, or without text at an arbitrary point in the content – eg. `<h2><a id="my-anchor"></a> My heading</h2>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Revisiting my own question a year later because this is still something we need, the solution we came up with is to simply wrap the RichText html serialization, and putting fragment id injection on top:

```py
import re
from django import template
from django.utils.text import slugify
from wagtail.core.rich_text import RichText

# We'll be wrapping the original RichText.__html__(), so make
# sure we have a reference to it that we can call.
__original__html__ = RichText.__html__

# This matches an h1/.../h6, using a regexp that is only
# guaranteed to work because we know that the source of
# the HTML code we'll be working with generates nice
# and predictable HTML code (and note the non-greedy
# "one or more" for the heading content).
heading_re = r"<h([1-6])([^>]*)>(.+?)</h\1>"


def add_id_attribute(match):
    """
    This is a regexp replacement function that takes
    in the above regex match results, and then turns:
        <h1>some text</h1>
    Into:
        <h1><a id="some-text"></a><a href="#some-text">some text</a></h1>
    where the id attribute value is generated by running
    the heading text through Django's slugify() function.
    """
    n = match.group(1)
    attributes= match.group(2)
    text_content = match.group(3)
    id = slugify(text_content)
    return f'<h{n}{attributes}><a id="{id}"></a><a href="#{id}">{text_content}</a></h{n}>'


def with_heading_ids(self):
    """
    We don't actually change how RichText.__html__ works, we just replace
    it with a function that does "whatever it already did", plus a
    substitution pass that adds fragment ids and their associated link
    elements to any headings that might be in the rich text content.
    """
    html = __original__html__(self)
    return re.sub(heading_re, add_id_attribute, html)


# Rebind the RichText's html serialization function such that
# the output is still entirely functional as far as wagtail
# can tell, except with headings enriched with fragment ids.
RichText.__html__ = with_heading_ids
```

This works rather well, does not require any hacking in draftail or wagtail, and is very easy to enable/disable simply by loading this code as part of the server startup process (we have it living in our wagtailcustom_tags.py file, so when Django loads up all template tag sets, the RichText "enrichment" kicks in automatically).

We had initially tried to extend the `... | richtext` template filter, but while that's entirely possible, that only works for custom blocks we ourselves wrote, with our own custom templates, and so turned out to not be a solution given the idea that it should "just work".

Comment: This is awesome. Tested Wagtail 2.13

Comment: I can see the point of the second `<a>` (if we want to make the heading clickable), but for the first one, just putting the id on the `<h{n}>` tag would be better.

So, I'd go with `<h{n} id="{id}"><a href="#{id}">{text_content}</a></h{n}>'` for a clickable heading, and simply `<h{n} id="{id}">{text_content}</h{n}>` for a non-clickable one.

Comment: That's up to you, but I definitely wouldn't, because CSS means the actual heading content may not be in the same place that the heading tag is, and users expect to navigate to "the thing you can see", not just "the top-left of the heading tag's bounding box location in the DOM".

Comment: How can I get this working with v5? The RichText import seems to have changed.

Comment: Probably worth asking on the Wagtail repo or their slack (my job no longer involves Wagtail so I have no idea what changed)

Answer (score 0):

To have control over the structure of your page body, it's preferable to encourage users to use heading blocks, rather than headings within the rich text block. Then you can have a heading block type which has two fields, a 'text' and an 'id', and you can [specify a template](http://wagtail.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0/topics/streamfield.html#template-rendering) that outputs the `h` element with the `id` attribute.

```
class Heading2Block(blocks.StructBlock):
    heading = blocks.CharBlock(classname='full title')
    link_id = blocks.CharBlock(help_text='For making hyperlinks to this heading')

    class Meta:
        template = 'blocks/h2.html'
```

Put the following in `blocks/h2.html`:

```
<h1{% if value.link_id %} id="{{ value.link_id|slugify }}"{% endif %}>{{ value.heading }}</h1>
```

In earlier versions of Wagtail it was possible to remove the `h` widget from the Hallo.js rich text editor, and this was a good way of encouraging user adoption of the heading block. Similar restriction is not currently present in Draftail, but there is a [pull request](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/4332) which reimplements it.

Comment: As @Alexey points out, customising Draftail to do this instead is probably a better prospect than it ever was with hallo.js, but the above is less work.

Comment: I also realise I've simply assumed that you're using Stream Field and a Rich Text block, rather than a RichTextField directly on the page model.

Comment: Also in the spitit of the Zen of Wagtail, forcing content creators to break up their content is thinking with a dev hat on. Would be fine if the audience was other devs, but it very much isn't. Editing draftail to make fragment linking work seems the way forward.

Comment: I disagree with that interpretation. The editor should not be using the rich text field to generate page _structure_ in a WYSIWYG fashion, merely formatted text. Making the headings (or images, or blockquotes) into their own block types takes the structure out of the rich text field, and as a bonus puts the markup in the hands of the developer. This particular case is a slightly greyer area. I'd say if the `id` attribute were auto-generated then a Draftail feature would cover it, but for something that the editor interacts with, a separate block is the better home.